# Dash lens does not search general stuff

Tags: 14.04, lenses

I don't know why, but my dash lens does not search general stuff like Editor,  Libre Office , etc

[image]

I also don't know how to open these stuff without dash lens!

Comment: I think you might mean "Libre Office". Does a search for that bring the right results?

Comment: @javascriptisfuture "Libre Office" does not work. P.S. it is not only Libre Office but also other general stuff.

Comment: Try clicking "Filter results". Something might have disabled search for programs

Comment: @javascriptisfuture I have already tried, there is not the single disabled item

Comment: What if you look at the applications tab (the strange "A" in the bottom). Does that show any applications?

Comment: @javascriptisfuture No it doesn't show any application. It shows message **"Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search"**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16672/discussion-between-javascript-is-future-and-rutviksutaria).

Comment: Start restarting it might help

Comment: @Freddy Thanks, but problem already solved by LinuxStudent in chat room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install the package `unity-scope-home` by typing the following in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home`, and then restart the computer. Sometimes, the updating process removes the unity scopes, and this package installs them all.